# How to set 'GIT_WORK_TREE' to specific driver in computer

Tags: git, setup-deployment

I'm trying using Git hook to deploy mt project in FTP.

By the way, I use 'CYGWIN' to build.

Here's my environment and settings.

**FTP in remote**

> C:\cygwin64\test_ftp\

**Cygwin in remote**

> C:\cygwin64\

**remote's root**

> C:\cygwin64\home\Administrator\

**git/hooks/post-receive**

```
#!/bin/sh

DEPLOY_DIR=~/../../test_ftp
echo "Start deploying..."
GIT_WORK_TREE=$DEPLOY_DIR git checkout -f
echo "Deployment is completed."
```

It works fine.

"git push" will trigger "post-receive" and deploy files in "C:\cygwin64\test_ftp\".

.

Now I want to change the path of "test_ftp" to "C:\test_ftp\",
I try to set "DEPLOY_DIR=~/../../../test_ftp" and run "git push".

Error occurs in deploy task:

> remote: fatal: This operation must be run in a work tree

Is there any way to set GIT_WORK_TREE's path out of cygwin??

Comment: try `/c/test_ftp/` instead

Comment: Not working.
> remote: fatal: Could not switch to '/c/test_ftp/': No such file or directory

Comment: Found answer later.

Comment: You should post thet answer as *the answer* to your own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer later.

1. Edit the file "C:\ctgwin64\etc\passwd".

   > Replace "/home/Administrator" to "/cygdrive/c".
2. Edit the file "C:\ctgwin64\etc\sshd_config".

   > Set "StrictModes no"
   >   Set "AuthorizedKeysFile /path/to/your/authorized_keys"
3. Restart the "CYGWIN sshd" service.
4. Try to push something in client side.

It works!!

Now I can login with key, triggered "post-receive" as usual and deploy files in "C:\test_ftp".